# Python: Parse next page's url from html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to parse next page's url.
I used to parse it successfully with the example below:

```
<a href="/FrontEnd/SearchPartsResult?Page=2" rel="next">»</a>
```

Code:

```
url_n=soup3.find('',rel = 'next')['href']
```

But when I do it with another one, it doesn't work:

```
<a href='/showroom.php?cate_name_eng_lv1=news-and-culture&p=1' class='next' >next</a>
```

I tried this:

```
url_n=soup3.find('',class = 'next')['href']
```

or this:

```
url_n=soup.select_one('.next')['href']
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: does this work `url_n=soup3.find('', class_ = 'next')['href']`? notice the underscore.

Comment: @OmarEinea yes! why do I need an underscore? Never thought of it before.

Comment: it's an official workaround as the word `class` is reserved in Python.

Comment: `class` is reserved keyword so you have to use `class_ = "next"` or dictionary  `{"class": "next"}`

Comment: I tried with `soup.select_one('.next')['href'] ` and it worked. What is your issue here? There is nothing wrong with the expression i just mentioned. You should better reveal the link to get a quicker answer.

Comment: @Shahin I tried it again and it worked well. Thanks for letting me know!